# How to not receiving PubNub Push Notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, pubnub

In My App I send push notification to the app via Pubnub, and after the user logged out from the app, the push notification should stop!

I try to unsubscribe Pubnub channel, like this:

```
client?.unsubscribeFromAll()
```

but I still got push notification!!

My question is : How to prevent receiving the push notification?

Is it by unsubscribe the channels, or this way is wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Real-time channels and push notification enabling / disabling - not linked to each other and if explicitly push notifications has been enabled they should be disabled in manually as well. Unsubscription is just disconnection from real-time data channels.

Use code bellow to disable all push notifications for specified `devicePushToken`:

```
client?.removeAllPushNotificationsFromDeviceWithPushToken(devicePushToken, andCompletion: { (status) in

    if !status.error { /* Handle push notification disable completed successfully. */ }
    else { /* Handle push notification disable did fail. */ }
})
```

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: @monlight
thanks a lot for your answer, but I have a problem: my app have two kind of users: normal user, driver user
normal user subscribe channels, and driver user subscribe different channels. 
the special case that I've faced is when I logged in as a normal user, then I logged out and then logged in as driver user, here I got the notifications of normal user and driver user.
so with your answer, I won't solve this case, right?

Comment: @Rawan suggested API call disable push notifications for all channels where it has been enabled using specified `devicePushToken`. So, when you log out and call this method, it will disable push notifications from all channels on which they has been enabled using `devicePushToken` - in this case driver won't get any updates from user's channels and vice versa.